# setting DHCP on an interface when it comes UP

Tags: networking, macos

When I tether my MacBook Pro via USB-C cable to my Linux mobile device, in MacOS an interface `en7` gets created on the fly. The mobile runs a NetworkManager with a DHCP server part. I can use the command `sudo ipconfig set en7 DHCP` and this brings an IP addr 10.42.0.18 into this interface (the mobile, which acts now as AP to Internet, has 10.42.0.1 and sets up everything incl. routing and NAT).

How this ipconfig can be done automatically when the interface comes up?